# Can you geo-tag a facebook post?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

I am developing an iphone app and using facebook graph API. I need to know weather I can geo tag a facebook post ?

The feed dialog does not specify any attributes related to location.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Can anyone shed some light on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tag a post with a location, you don't post to the `/feed` endpoint, you post to the `/checkins` endpoint.  You can see some brief documentation regarding it on the [Graph API Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) page under the *Publishing* header, which tells you which arguments you can post (coordinates, place (id), message, and tags (for who's with you).  There's a little more information on the [Checkin Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/checkin/) page, but not a whole lot about actually posting them.

Hope that helps - and I'm sorry for the mass confusion; I completely whiffed on what you were asking originally :P

Comment: So basically we can't post lat long values for a facebook post. Is it ?

Comment: correct; you can only geo-target cities, countries, regions, and by language selected on facebook (you could post to all Pirate Speak users, if you like - there's a surprising number of them...haha).  But not to a specific lat/long

Comment: Well I am bit confused now . I don't want target any location and group. I just want to specify the location of the post . is this unavailable on a facebook post ?

Comment: If you're posting as a user - you can specify which of the users friends see it (no geo location).  If you're posting as a page, you can specify Cities, Regions, Countries, and "Locales" (languages).

Comment: Sorry If am dragging this  ,But I rally need to be clear on this. I don't want to targe or restrict my post in way. I just want to share my location from the phone.

Comment: AH! I completely mis-understood! i'll fix my answer!